# ::first-letter pseudo-element not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, pseudo-element

I cannot for the life of me figure this one out.  I just want to style the dollar sign to be a different color and I would like to avoid using another element around the dollar sign.

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>John Dow</strong> <div>$5,849,487<sup>84</sup></div></li>
    <li><strong>David Jones</strong> <div>$5,498,364<sup>01</sup></div></li>
    <li><strong>Susie Smith</strong> <div>$5,098,276<sup>35</sup></div></li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
li::first-letter {
    color: blue;
}
li div::first-letter {
    color: red;
}​​
```

The blue works, the red does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/KUzUp/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be due to the `$` character not being interpreted as a letter character by Firefox, based on the discovery that replacing the `$` with a letter character (`A`, `B`, `C`...) causes the demo to work:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>David Wilcox</strong> <div>A$5,849,487<sup>84</sup></div></li>
    <li><strong>David Cowee</strong> <div>B$5,498,364<sup>01</sup></div></li>
    <li><strong>D.J. Johnson</strong> <div>C$5,098,276<sup>35</sup></div></li>
</ul>​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KUzUp/4/).

Revisiting this question, though, it's worth noting that now you could use CSS generated-content to both supply, and style, a first-character, using `::before`:

```
li div::before {
    content: '$';
    color: red;
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><strong>David Wilcox</strong> 
        <div>5,849,487<sup>84</sup>
        </div>
    </li>
    <!-- siblings removed for brevity -->
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KUzUp/48/).

Comment: Thanks for the demo, but @StephanNeubert beat you to it.

Comment: Hover your mouse over the **'...mins ago'** text, and you'll see a time-stamp in the tooltip that shows the exact time of posting the answer. We were near enough the same time as makes no difference, but I was, I think, a little faster. =) But, to reiterate: 'near enough to make no difference.'

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  Stephan's post appeared first (not sure why), but he was most certainly not the first to post.  Since I awarded points to the "first answer", I have dutifully reassigned points to you.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter who was *first*, what matters is 'who helped you the most.' Though, obviously, I appreciate the rep of course!

Comment: For answers which are equally helpful, then it comes down to who's first in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Everything works as it should do: `::first-letter` selects the first letter, but "$" is not a letter but a special character.

Comment: Wow...  I would have never guessed that it was so literal.

Comment: For what it's worth, the spec on this says: `Punctuation (i.e, characters defined in Unicode [UNICODE] in the "open" (Ps), "close" (Pe), "initial" (Pi). "final" (Pf) and "other" (Po) punctuation classes), that precedes or follows the first letter should be included.`  Dollar sign is in the "Sc" class in Unicode, though, which is, as Stefan said, "Special characters".  If you'd had a quotation mark there, the behavior would have been different...

Answer (score 1):

Others already explained why it doesn't work, so, a small fix for you to consider: give your money div a class, eg

```
<li><strong>David Wilcox</strong> <div class="money">5,849,487<sup>84</sup></div></li>
```

take out the literal $, and put it in `:before` content, eg:

```
.money:before {
    content: '$';
    ...
}
```

Now you can style it however you like.

Comment: If you can modify the content, why not wrap the “$” in a `span`, instead of making its very appearance depend on CSS?

Comment: You mean its content depend on CSS (since its appearance will in any case)?  No super-strong reason, except that `:before` will require less markup, and if the content of `.money` is populated programmatically it will allow for cleaner data being passed around.

Comment: I agree to Jukka: I would avoid adding content via css whenever I can - that's the point of separating content and presentation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The class is not even necessary as I was already targeting the DIV in my original example.  Unfortunately the client is paying for IE7 support (which is an addon these days).  Also, I will be dealing with content editors... and I don't want to explain how the dollar sign magically appears.  If it were my site, this would be a win.