# :first-letter pseudo-element not working in Firefox

Tags: css

The first letter pseudo element is not working in Firefox no matter what I do. It works in Chrome, Safari, and Opera but not Firefox.

Here is the piece of CSS:

```
.dyk
{
    font-family: Myanmar Sangam MN;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20pt;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.dyk:first-letter
{
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

Things I've tried:

- validating the html and CSS files
- CSS reset file

I have looked at my code over and over again but I cant figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Where is the markup, the actual text content, and a description of what “not working” means here?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Answer (score 2):

`:first-letter` in CSS2 or `::first-letter` in CSS3 only works on block level elements, it doesn't work on inline elements in Firefox. If you are for example trying to use it in a span it won't work in Firefox. You can learn more about it's specifications here https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#first-letter-application

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me, does a `<span>` with `"display: inline-block;"` count as a block-level element? Some references say yes (and it seems to work with Safari and Chrome). I don't have issues with Firefox on Mac, but I'm told Firefox on Windows and Linux show some issues.

Comment: @scottbb Yes it does work on `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a user had a similar problem, maybe this will shed some light! [::first-letter pseudo-element not working in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12753822/first-letter-pseudo-element-not-working-in-firefox)

In a bare bones example it works, hope this helps:

```
<style type="text/css">
.dyk {
    font-family: Myanmar Sangam MN;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 20pt;
    width: 250px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.dyk:first-letter { font-size: 60px; }
</style>
<div class="dyk">This is a test!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try `.dyk::first-letter` instead of `.dyk:first-letter`.

That's how the W3Schools example does it.