# css first-letter exclude other tags

Tags: html, css

I have a page generated by WordPress which HTML looks similar to the HTML below. I would like to the first-letter of my `div` to have a different size, but when I try to add style for `p:first-letter`, all `p`'s change sizes. My problem is I can't remove the `p`-tags because these are automatically created.

```
<div class="div">
    <p>Paragraph 1</p> <!-- I need "P" in "Paragraph" in different size -->
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <blockquote><p>Text blockquote</p></blockquote>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/hdNDh/

Comment: like this - [first letter of chld p](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hdNDh/3/) or this - [first letter of first p](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/hdNDh/4/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [CSS child selector `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pattern-matching).

> > **E > F** - Matches any F element that is a child of an element E.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/hdNDh/1/)</kbd>

```
.div > p:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

**Edit:** It seems I misunderstood your question at first, if you need the first letter of the `div` only, simply set the pseudo-class on the `div` instead of on the `p`.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/hdNDh/6/)</kbd>

```
.div:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

**Edit2:** As mentioned in the comments below, for this to work in FF you need:

```
.div > p:first-child:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hdNDh/8/)</kbd>

This seems strange/weird behaviour, so I have had a bit of a look around and it seems that Firefox is more particular about the `:first-letter` pseudo-class than other browsers. One example is that it doesn't [count **special characters** to be **letters**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12753879), and therefore won't apply styles to them.

Results from testing a little bit just now: Firefox **doesn't count** the *first letter of the first child element* to be the same as *the first letter encountered within itself including child elements (even when there is no preceding text)*, whereas Chrome **does count** *the first letter of the first child element* to be the same as *the first letter encountered within itself including child elements (when there is no preceding text)*.

Comment: nice fliestra its help me as well

Comment: @Isherwood - Ah, it seems I misunderstood :) will fix it.

Comment: Thank you. I just add ohter selector p:first-child:first-letter to change just the first <p>

Comment: @Coelho, the double pseudo-class isn't needed, see my updated answer.

Comment: nice one.. just beware that if you use space before selector like this: `.div :first-letter` then that is applying to all child elements instead.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra: Your second example isn't working in FF 23

Comment: @Adrift - True, it seems you need `.div > p:first-child:first-letter` for this to work in FF, will edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of selectors:

http://jsfiddle.net/hdNDh/5/

```
.div > p:first-child:first-letter {
    font-size:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
.div > p:first-child::first-letter {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdNDh/2/

Comment: just asking.. why two colons for second selector? it is just you kept it or there is any meaning behind it :)

Comment: @Mr_Green: Extracted from [here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/before-after-css3/). With the introduction of CSS3, in order to make a differentiation between pseudo-classes and pseudo-elements (yes, they’re different), in CSS3 all pseudo-elements must use the double-colon syntax, and all pseudo-classes must use the single-colon syntax